# Sharepoint REST Field Property does not exist

Tags: rest, sharepoint, postman

I am using Postman for Chrome to test some simply stuff with Sharepoints REST Api.

Well - I get an error right in the beginning while trying to retrieve certain Fields from a List - here are some pictures:

SharePoint List:

[image]

Calling for CPU

[image]

Calling for RAM - which fails:

[image]

(EXmsg: Field Property 'RAM' does not exist)

Anyone has a clue? I do not understand this at all.

Thanks in Advance!

P.s.

When calling:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Anwendungen')/items
```

RAM will be displayed as a property of "zzfu" - dafuq?

Comment: Try with the internal name. First get all fields of the list with /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('xxx')/fields and see what is the internal name of the RAM field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs since `$select` query option accepts field *internal* name but **not** *display* name.

Having said that, you might need first to determine field internal name, for example:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Anwendungen')/fields?$select=InternalName&$filter=Title eq 'RAM'
```

Once the field internal is determined, you could query field value like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Anwendungen')/items?$select=<RAM internal name>
```

where `<RAM internal name>` is RAM field internal name.